# How to determine current i2c baudrate?

Tags: i2c

To set the I2C bus 1 baud rate by adding the following command to `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtparam=i2c_arm_baudrate=x
```

Where x is the desired baud rate.

But I've no such value, and how to determine current i2c baudrate ?

Btw, I did

```
gpio load i2c 400000
```

But run into

```
gpio: Unable to load/unload modules as this Pi has the device tree enabled.
  You need to run the raspi-config program (as root) and select the
  modules (SPI or I2C) that you wish to load/unload there and reboot.
```

But I already did it

Comment: is there some kind of a question about the `gpio load i2c 400000`? ... if there is, then please post it separately

Comment: `gpio load i2c` has been deprecated for years.  Do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) to check the baudrate.

Start the pigpio daemon with `sudo pigpiod -s 1` to sample at 1 MHz.  This should allow you to judge baudrates in the 400 kHz region.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an inexpensive 24Mhz logic analyzer for under 10 bucks from your favorite supplier. I plugs in a USB 3 or USB3 port. It is easy to install (in Linux) then connect the ground and channel 0. Once you get it to trigger you can see and measure whatever you want, it will also decode the message if you want. It has cursors so you can pick and chose what edges etc you want to measure.